# System.out.println(); won't write in my if statement with stages

Tags: java, if-statement, println, adventure

I'm trying to make a text based adventure story with options and different scenarios. When I use `if(stage == *)` it does not activate sysout messages, only in my switch statements or it adds it after I give an input.

```
private static int stage = 0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String opt = in.next().toLowerCase();

if(stage == 0) {
    System.out.println("Do you go left or right?");
    switch(opt) {
        case "right":
            System.out.println("Swamp, you go through the thicket and move forward.");
            stage = 10;
            break;
        case "left":
            System.out.println("You find an open field with flowers all over.");
            stage++;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: stage ==* is not a statement

Comment: Are you saying the "Do you go left or right?" printout doesn't show, but the "Swamp..." or "You find..." ones do?

Comment: What function is this inside of? I don't see a "main" anywhere.

Comment: Exactly, @JohnKugelman , I need it to print that too, or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: Hi Eric, please do not add the solution to your question and/or edit "solved" into the title. Instead, mark an answer to mark your question as solved. If none of the answers are good enough for you and you did solve it by yourself, provide your own answer (in the form of a real answer) and mark that one.

Answer (score 4):

You are reading from input before to ask the question, that's why your question is printed after you give an input.

`String opt = in.next().toLowerCase();` should go after `System.out.println("Do you go left or right?");` because reading from input is blocking

Comment: @EricLjungkrantz If this answers your question click the checkmark to mark it as accepted.